# Improve video quality when using quickblox javascript SDk

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I am using quickblox javascript SDK for video calling.Everything has been implemented and running, but the video quality on the connected device is poor.I checked out the javascript docs by quickblox, found nothing there.

Does anyone know how the video quality can be improved ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you use this solution? http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-web#One_to_One_Video_.2F_Voice_Calls

Comment: @Igor yes, i am using this only.

Answer (score -1):

By default WebRTC supports auto adjustment of video quality based on the network bandwidth

So there are now any settings to increase/decrease the video quality

Do you actually have good network bandwidth?

Comment: Yes, the network bandwidth is very good and this doesn' t seem to be the issue.

Comment: Invalid answer.